# excluding certain properties from a type definition

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to exclude some specific type declaration on the `Window` object.

The first step i thought of was just creating another type with the subset of definitions i'd like and after that seeing if I can altogether redeclare the `Window` module.

Let's take the first step.

```js
interface IgnoredWindowProps { 
    alert: any,
    applicationCache: any
//...
}

type WindowKeySubsetUnion = Exclude<keyof Window, keyof IgnoredWindowProps>;
```

Now, the `WindowKeySubsetUnion` contains a union of the keys of the `Window` declaration that were not ignored. I'm having trouble re-mapping those union keys to the implementation types of Window. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean by "re-mapping keys to implementation types".  Do you just want [`Pick`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1432-L1437)`<Window, WindowKeySubsetUnion>`?

Comment: yes, exactly that :) please answer the question so that I may mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) called `Pick<T, K>` [defined](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1432-L1437) in the standard TypeScript library which returns a supertype of `T` that is only known to contain the properties with keys in `K`.  In your case, you are looking to widen `Window` to a type only known to have keys in `WindowKeySubsetUnion`:

```
type WiderWindow = Pick<Window, WindowKeySubsetUnion>;
```

Also note that there is a related type function, usually called `Omit<T, K>` which is not defined in the standard library, but is usually rendered like this:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

If you use that, you can get your desired type as

```
type WiderWindow = Omit<Window, keyof IgnoredWindowProps>;
```

Either way should work.  Hope that helps; good luck!